# assert failed. cond="uid != 0", msg="Assert in TypeId::LookupByName: ns3::UniformRandomRectanglePositionAllocator not found"

Tags: c++, ns-3

When I try to run my code here:

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Create nodes
  uint32_t nNodes = 10; // Number of nodes
  NodeContainer nodes;
  nodes.Create (nNodes);

  // Create a 2D space for the nodes
  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::UniformRandomRectanglePositionAllocator",
                                 "X", DoubleValue (0.0),
                                 "Y", DoubleValue (0.0),
                                 "Width", DoubleValue (100.0),
                                 "Height", DoubleValue (100.0));
  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
  mobility.Install (nodes);

  // Create the CSMA/CA protocol
  CsmaHelper csma;
  csma.SetChannelAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (5000000));
  csma.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", TimeValue (NanoSeconds (6560)));

  // Install the CSMA/CA protocol on the nodes
  NetDeviceContainer devices = csma.Install (nodes);

  // Run the simulation
  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (10.0));
  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();

  return 0;
}
```

I got an error that is "assert failed. cond="uid != 0", msg="Assert in TypeId::LookupByName: ns3::UniformRandomRectanglePositionAllocator not found", +0.000000000s -1 file=../src/core/model/type-id.cc, line=834
". At now, I don't know how to solve this problem, maybe the error in my ns3 version or something. So that someones help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

`ns3::UniformRandomRectanglePositionAllocator` does not exist in the latest version of ns-3.

However, `ns3::RandomRectanglePositionAllocator` does exist. Just set X, and Y to a uniform random variable like the default value `ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.0|Max=1.0]`

```
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::RandomRectanglePositionAllocator",
                                 "X", StringValue("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.0|Max=100.0]"),
                                 "Y", StringValue("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.0|Max=100.0]"));
```